# jQuery event binding inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I thought I understood jQuery, evidently not. Why, in this example, does the first textbox register clicks but not the second?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4

/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

    captureKeys = function(event)
    {
    alert("foo");
    }
    $(document).ready(function()
            {
        $('#UsingJQuery').bind('keyup', function(){alert('bar');});
            });

</script>
</head>
<body id="contentText" >
    <input type="text" id="UsingPlainJavaScript" onkeyup="captureKeys()"/>
  <input type="text" id="UsingJQuery"/>
  
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: OK, I've fixed the typo but it's still not working..

Comment: Could it be that your selector in Javascript (`usingJQuery`) doesn't match the ID of the input tag (`UsingJQuery`)? I believe the `id` attribute is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's amazing (in hindsight) how I can miss such obvious mistakes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is asking for trouble:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min"/>
```

You need a `</script>` to have a valid markup

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min"></script>
```

That is a big **NoNo** and might be the reason for your problem. Another thing is, there is no `.js` in your filename? Make sure that your `jQuery lib` has the correct name aswell.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3

Answer (score 3):

Because the ID of the second input element is `UsingJQuery` (capital *U*), not `usingJQuery`.

```
$('#UsingJQuery').bind('keyup', function(){alert('bar');});
```

should do it.

**Update:**

The error must be somewhere else, your code is correct. See: http://jsfiddle.net/H2xye/

Maybe you did not include jQuery correctly:

```
src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"
```

you are missing `.js` at the end of the path. At least this is the standard naming, maybe you renamed it.
The error console should tell you more.

*Update2: See jAndy's answer regarding the `</script>` tag. This is probably the other problem!*

Answer (score 1):

Please change 
from

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min"/>`

to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"/>`